# Capturing the SYN, ACK, FIN Packets and sending it in my own way in Android

Tags: android, tcp, network-programming, download

I'm currently working on a project(Android Download Manager).
What I need to do is, I need to capture the SYN, ACK, FIN Packets and send them in my own way. Also I need to increase the cwnd size manually. Is it possible? if so can you please explain me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to 'capture the SYN, ACK, FIN packets and send them in my own way' *why?*

Comment: @EJP : its that the TCP typically uses the TCP slow start methodology which is bit slow. What I need to do is to increase the speed by making it TCP fast start. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is definitely no way to do this. You cannot connect any equipment that does this to the Internet. You are almost certainly mistaken in thinking that trying to speed up the initial handshake will have any significant effect. Typically paying attention to socket send and receive buffer sizes has the most effect on TCP throughput, along with connection pooling.